Using Dagster to load polars.LazyFrame from S3 via PolarsParquetIOManager fails with "Generic S3 error: Missing bucket name"
I'm trying to pass a polars.LazyFrame between two assets with code that roughly looks like so (omitting details in order to get a minimal reproducible example):
@asset(
    io_manager_key="polars_parquet_io_manager",
)
def upstream() -> pl.LazyFrame:
    return pl.LazyFrame(...)

@asset()
def downstream(upstream: pl.LazyFrame) -> ...:
    upstream.collect()

defs = Definitions(
    assets=[
        upstream,
        downstream,
    ],
    resources={
        "polars_parquet_io_manager": PolarsParquetIOManager(
            base_dir=f"s3://{get_dagster_bucket_name()}/path/to/folder"
        ),
    },
)

The upstream asset materializes and stores to S3 fine. However, calling .collect() in downstream fails with:

The above exception was caused by the following exception: polars.exceptions.ComputeError: Generic S3 error: Missing bucket name

I was hoping that adding an IO manager will help abstract away the bucket name / file location, but surprisingly this isn't working. Is there anything I could be missing in this setup?
